# Using if statment with models field django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm trying to use if statement in the template but it doesn't work
in template:

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {% if post.tag == 'book' %}
    <div class="product-item ">
        <div class="pi-pic ">
            <img src="{{post.Img.url}} " alt=" "> 
            {% if post.tag %}
                <div class="sale ">{{post.tag}}</div>
            {%endif%}
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
{%endfor%}
```

*models.py*

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    Img = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/',null =True) 
    tag=models.ForeignKey('tags',on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
class tags(models.Model):
    tag_name= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.tag_name
```

and in
views.py :

```
def post_list(request):
    tags=tags.objects.all()
    posts= Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')   
    return render(request, 'post/index2.html', {'posts': posts})
```

Comment: Looks like you haven't ended your first `if`

Comment: it was a problem with pasting the code here main code is ok

Comment: I have eddited, check if your `if` blocks matches or not. Also, add your `views.py`

Comment: thank you very much but it doesn't work

Comment: Okay... it will not work. I have just editted your post. Your work is to see if the template matches with the current code or not. Also, to add `views.py` for that template

Comment: this template works fine problem is when I add if statement and please check the view.py

Comment: when I delete if statement everything works fine but i don't know what is wrong with the if statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

post.tag is an object not a string `book`, i think you need to change it to
`{% if post.tag and post.tag.tag_name == 'book' %}`
or add method `get_tag_string` to your `Post` model

```
def get_tag_string(self):
    return str(self.tag)
```

and then you can check `{% if post.get_tag_string == 'book' %}`

and then you don't need second if, it will always be `True` if first one is `True`

Comment: are you sure that there is tag `string`?

Comment: I think so my code is exactly like the one Iv posted here

Comment: if you added method `get_tag_string`. add `print(self.tag)` at the beginning of it and you will see what tags do you have

Comment: the tag book really exists i can even use {{post.tag }} and see it but I don't know what is wrong with if statement

Comment: it could be `'book'`, `'Book'` `'book '`, `' book '`, `'BOOK'`, check what do you have there

Comment: it was 'book  ' with one extra space. thank you again

Answer (score 1):

As your `tags` model contains `__str__` which is giving a string value, when object is printed just for the sake of easiness. So, your comparision of `post.tag` *instance* is with *string*, `book`. That's why your `if` block was not working as expected. So, comparing with `tag_name` attribute will work:

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {% if post.tag.tag_name == 'book' %}   
    <div class="product-item ">
        <div class="pi-pic">
            <img src="{{post.Img.url}}" alt=""> 
            {% if post.tag %}
                <div class="sale">{{post.tag}}</div>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Are you sure you properly followed what I said. `post.tag.tag__name`

Comment: yes. excatly this  {% if post.tag.tag_name == 'book' %}

Comment: Can you make sure your tag_name has `book` or not?

Comment: thank you very much yes the problem was one more extra space